# Retain Reading Position Of Scrolling Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I am building a column with dynamic content being appended to the top of the column similar to the style of TweetDeck.

Now if I were to scroll half way down the div to view content, the content being added to the top causes the div to jump from the scrolled position, making any content down the column not readable if a lot of content is being added to the column.

Does anyone know of a way is CSS or jQuery to hold the positon that the user is at, yet allow the content to still be added at the top?

Sorry I cant provide a JS Fiddle, data is in a dev environment

*Update - Example HTML Markup*

```
<div class="results" id="results9016">
  <article>
    <img alt="Dave" src="normal.jpg">
    <div class="data">
      <p class="user"><a target="_blank" href="#">dave</a></p>
      <p class="message">Message</p><p class="datetime">24 Apr 17:16:23</p></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img alt="Dave" src="normal.jpg">
    <div class="data">
      <p class="user"><a target="_blank" href="#">dave</a></p>
      <p class="message">Message</p><p class="datetime">24 Apr 17:16:23</p></div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <img alt="Dave" src="normal.jpg">
    <div class="data">
      <p class="user"><a target="_blank" href="#">dave</a></p>
      <p class="message">Message</p><p class="datetime">24 Apr 17:16:23</p></div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Each article element is being added using a jQuery .prepend();

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Have you tried scrolling the container the same amount of the height of the new div upon adding it?

Comment: What jQuery method are you using to append the content? .append()? If you could show us the general HTML structure it'd be helpful.

Comment: No I have not tried this approach, the height of the divs/content being appended at the top can vary, which may be an issue in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try caching the document's scroll position before prepend and resetting it immediately afterward:

```
var addTweet = function() {
    var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#results9016').prepend($newTweet);
    $('html, body').scrollTop(scrollPosition);
}
```

[Here's a fiddle of it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/27XkU/) Note: depending on your code, you may want to scroll a container instead of the entire document.